# How to specify multiple values for a multiValued field in solr?

Tags: json, search, solr, filter, field

So basically i need a simple answer to a simple question. I have a multivalued text field by the name of location. The structure of location is basically like this:

```
 location: [
           "united states",
           "united kingdom",
           "taiwan",
           "taipei"
           ]
```

So what I want to do is basically get only the entries that have the exact specific arrays that I specify. For example:

```
'location: taiwan AND taipei'
or
'location: united states AND united kingdom'
```

so the first example would reutnr all the entries that have both taiwan and taipei in their location field and ignore any entries that have only taiwan or only taipei in their location fields.

An example of what is working for me:

I have a field address of type text ( it is not multivalued ), I can get all the entries that contain a text like "dislike yoyo" by doing the following:

```
 'address: dislike yoyo'
```

Also If I have two fields address and location then how can I filter the entries using both of these fields? I mean something like this:

```
 'address: this is not me AND location: taiwan'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you want with the query

```
location:taiwan AND location:taipei
```

The example you gave of

```
location: taiwan AND Taipei
```

will find all documents that have taiwan in the location field and Taipei in the default field (which if you haven't changed it will be set to the field named text).

Comment: You can also use `location:(taiwan AND taipei)`